# How to get wallet of user if its delete once in hypeledger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I need one help as I have confusion in one condition let's user register and enroll to the network and it's secret which is generate at time of registration saved in mongodb but somehow it's wallet got deleted so we need to register the user again or we can get wallet again just enroll user again with same secret?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can enroll the Identity again using the same secret.  Assuming that the max number of enrollments has not been exceeded - but the default is "-1" (unlimited).

FYI each time you enroll you get different credentials, but they are valid for the same Identity.

Comment: Yes I have done the same I am getting result as you mentioned however I have condition if the user  wallet get deleted from filesystem it's not working after enroll again also it not create wallet again

Comment: hi @R Thatcher can we regenerate the wallet in hyperledger using just enroll the user again?

Comment: @Abhirock yes, import the identity, with the given identity label to the wallet path and it should create the user wallet - for FileSystemWallet - see this example https://gist.github.com/mahoney1/4667768244fee45e8f87a24fce3e9d26#file-gistfile1-txt-L50. If referring to CouchDB based wallet - see base class (Wallet) methods for CouchDB https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/module-fabric-network.CouchDBWallet.html

Comment: Hi Paul,I tried but I don't get result as I need please help me know I am tying on IBM blockchain